# jQuery Mobile Center Inputs with Margins

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Spent an embarrassing amount of time researching and trying various fixes to align "things" (inputs, images, buttons, etc) center vs left in JQM.  It seems one possible "best of both worlds" solution to accommodate large and small displays would be to provide an EASY WAY to center inputs, etc. giving a small margin on each side so users can see them clearly vs running them all the way to the edge of the browser.  Here's my failed attempt to accomplish an input that takes up 90% the screen and is centered.  Its like it's aligned center within the DIV but the whole DIV is then aligned left so it nets left align.  Tried various combinations of DIV order and at this point I "div-up"! :)  Any help is much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyTitle</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/centerstyle.css">
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Centered and with margins</h1>
</div>
<div class="center-wrapper">
<label for="UserName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" name="UserName" placeholder="User Name">
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Footer</h4>
</div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.center-wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
}
.center-wrapper * {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/gmjudo85/1/)

Comment: Yes but when I tried that with JQM the input spans the entire screen edge to edge in both IE and Chrome.  Its like an override I can't seem to locate.  I can style what I need independent of JQM but we're looking at integrating it.  So how to center AND use JQM is the goal.  Given all the other posts I hope they recognize the need for this soon.

Comment: Have you tried inline styles on the input element, or give the input an `id` or `class` name and try that way?

Comment: Oddly, if I change your fiddle .center-wrapper to 90% and remove the input style it seems to be closer, however still not correct because everything including header/footer is 90%.  I just want to be able to control certain DIVs and leave the others alone.

Comment: Yes, tried inline styles,  Tried most of the threads here and other places.  The reason I posted the entire HTML is other threads only address one aspect, trying to show exactly the code in play.  Should I screen shot the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQM you should really wrap everything in a data-role="page" div and the content in a content div like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Centered and with margins</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="center-wrapper">
            <label for="UserName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" name="UserName" placeholder="User Name" />
            <button>I am a button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">        
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you just set the width of the center-wrapper div and assign an auto margin to center it:

```
.center-wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bdy8crzs/)**

Comment: I believe I have tried this already but not sure I had this exact combo haha.  Thanks for all comments/responses, BRB....

Comment: That was the combination I needed, what a silly problem.  Thanks for the DIV-ine intervention :)